# Get child hierarchy path till parent in java

Tags: java

I have a scenario to get a child hierarchy structure of a field till parent for doing field level validations.
Can someone provide some solution.

**Pojo classes**

**Student.java**

```
 package com.poc.next.validations;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Student {
    private String studentName;
    private List<Subject> subjects;

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public List<Subject> getSubjects() {
        if (subjects == null) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return subjects;
    }

    public void setSubjects(List<Subject> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }
}
```

**Subject.java**

```
package com.poc.next.validations;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Subject {

    private String subjectName;
    private List<RevisionMarks> revisionMarks;

    public String getSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }

    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    public List<RevisionMarks> getRevisionMarks() {
        if (revisionMarks == null) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return revisionMarks;
    }

    public void setRevisionMarks(List<RevisionMarks> revisionMarks) {
        this.revisionMarks = revisionMarks;
    }
}
```

**RevisionMarks.java**

```
package com.poc.next.validations;

public class RevisionMarks {

    private Integer mark;
    private String revision;

    public Integer getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(Integer mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    public String getRevision() {
        return revision;
    }

    public void setRevision(String revision) {
        this.revision = revision;
    }
}
```

Now we are adding a validation to check whether the given mark in RevisionMarks class in valid or not. if it is equal to zero I have to add it to error dto and send it back to UI. The challenge here is i have to provide the field name dynamic in hierarchy like "subjects[0].revisionMarks[0].mark".

**Main class**
**RevisionValidation.java**

```
package com.poc.next.validations;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class RevisionValidation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = populateStudentData();
        Iterator<Subject> iterator = student.getSubjects().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Subject subject = (Subject) iterator.next();
            RevisionMarks revisionMarks = subject.getRevisionMarks().get(0);
            System.out.println(revisionMarks.getMark());
            if (revisionMarks.getMark() == 0) {
                ErrorDTO errorDTO = new ErrorDTO(true, "Invalid Marks", "Error", "subjects[0].revisionMarks[0].mark",
                        "invalid_mark");
                System.out.println(errorDTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Student populateStudentData() {
        List<RevisionMarks> revisionMarks = new ArrayList<>();
        RevisionMarks revisionMark = new RevisionMarks();
        revisionMark.setMark(0);
        revisionMark.setRevision("Test 1");
        revisionMarks.add(revisionMark);

        List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        subject.setSubjectName("CS");
        subject.setRevisionMarks(revisionMarks);
        subjects.add(subject);

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setStudentName("Sample");
        student.setSubjects(subjects);
        return student;
    }

}
```

How can I dynamically create the fieldpath like "subjects[0].revisionMarks[0].mark". 
Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a counter that you increment at each iteration of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter:

```
    int counter = 0;
    Iterator<Subject> iterator = student.getSubjects().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Subject subject = (Subject) iterator.next();
        RevisionMarks revisionMarks = subject.getRevisionMarks().get(0);
        System.out.println(revisionMarks.getMark());
        if (revisionMarks.getMark() == 0) {
            ErrorDTO errorDTO = new ErrorDTO(true, "Invalid Marks", "Error", "subjects[" + counter + "].revisionMarks[0].mark",
                    "invalid_mark");
            System.out.println(errorDTO);
        }
        ++counter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use JSR3 validation instead of reinventing wheel.
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

You can add necessary annotations for each field in your POJO and add @Valid annotation to let validator check nested POJO objects.

The link 
https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/how-to-invoke-jsr-303-bean-validation-programmatically/ shows how to call the validator programmatically.

With the validation you can provide any messages and localize them, and the xpaths are built automatically pointing problems in POJO or nested POJOs.